# How to change datagridview columnname color or style?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]How can I change the color or type of the column name on a DataGridView in WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the DataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyle properly to false to make changes to the Style.Fore/BackColor property visible.

Answer (score 1):

Click the little triangle on the top right of the DGV, click edit columns, scroll to the column you want to change, and go to town in the property grid

To change the color, you'll want the  DefaultCellStyle -> Backcolor

to change the type of column, you'll want the...ColumnType property

Comment: This affects the column, not the header.

Comment: Here is solution: this.dataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="bank_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="#CCCCFF">.....try it
```

Comment: u have to jst add back colour proprertity

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackCo lor = Color.FromArgb(98, 110, 110);
dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackCo lor = Color.Black;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeCo lor = Color.White;
dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.Back Color = Color.Black;
dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 90, 90);
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(27, 30, 30);
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(5, 0, 5, 0);
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
```